# Can I apply changes across different databases on the same server using liquibase

Tags: sybase, liquibase

We have a large enterprise system which has many databases on a single server (Sybase)
Developers will make a change in one db, script it, then maybe make a change in another db, add that to the list of scripts and so on.

Our release then runs through these scripts making changes to the objects in different databases in the same order.

Reading the Liquibase documentation, it seems like it would work if you applied all the changes to one db, then another, then another. Which wouldnt really work in our case as a change in one db may rely a change done earlier on another db and vice versa.

How could I use Liquibase to do the same?

Comment: You're talking about different database schemas running in different databases on the same server? Just use liquibase to manage each schema separately and have 3 configurations under revision control.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to start looking at [Datical DB](http://www.datical.com) (disclaimer: I work at Datical), which is a set of tools and extensions around Liquibase to handle these kinds of situations.

Alternatively, you could do something similar, writing your own tools to control Liquibase. Liquibase is controllable at several different levels - you could use a scripting tool to execute the Liquibase command line, or you could use Java or Groovy (or any other language that integrates with tools in the JVM) and use the Liquibase classes more directly.

Answer (score 0):

Liquibase does not currently support connecting to multiple different databases. It is being considered for version 4.0.

If your databases are the same database instance but different schemas, you can use the schemaName attribute to target changeSets at different schemas from one changeSet to the next. You will need a single connection URL that has access to all of the schemas.

If your databases are different instances or not all accessible from a single connection URL, you can probably create custom change classes or extensions that allow you to run SQL against different connections, although that will not be as clean or easy as the schemaName option.